# VS Code: autocomplete in <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, script-tag

I can't get VS Code to complete my JS-code inside `<script>` tags in HTML-files. Yes, it helps me with closing tags and so on, but doesn't seem to care about my JS in HTML-files at all. However, in `.js` files the autocomplete feature works fine.

Is there a setting that I don't know about or should I use Notepad++ instead in this case?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [currently](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3465) not supported by vscode